# How to run kafka producer in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka. 
I have downloaded kafka 2.9.2-0.8.1.1. I have started zookeeper, broker, producer and consumer from command prompt. I successfully created a topic and sent a message.

Now I want to run the producer from eclipse. But I dont know how to to do that. I found some links like http://vulab.com/blog/?p=611 to do this but I am still not able to run it. Is this the correct process mentioned in the link? Do i really need to create maven project in eclipse? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: can you say me what error your getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Kafka Java API for creating kafka producer (if you intent to use JAVA). Using maven is highly recomended as it will help managing all the dependencies for you. But you are free to bypass maven if you are ready to manage all the required JARs by yourself.

[kafka wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) is another good place to look at.